# the value of the field moduleService is not Used

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

```
package com.maroclance.university.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class ModuleServiceTest {
public class ModuleServiceTest {

private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;


private static ModuleService moduleService;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
    moduleService=(ModuleService) context.getBean("moduleService");

}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    context.close();
}

@Test
public void test() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

i have the  warning that moduleService is not used 
when i execute my code i have this error

```
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.maroclance.model.Matiere.profMats[com.maroclance.model.ProfMat]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1401)
.
.
.
.
aused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.maroclance.model.Matiere.profMats[com.maroclance.model.ProfMat]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1068)
```

I'm really blocked

Comment: Your problem is in class com.maroclance.model.Matiere

Comment: okey but i dont know what to do ..this is my class Matiere

Comment: Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the classes `ProfMat` or `Module` has not mapped with Hibernate. The mapping should be defined via configuration. If you are using annotation configuration then put a `@Table` annotation on the associated classes and make sure that classes are scanned for annotations.

Comment: class prof_mat @SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "prof_mat", catalog = "gestionmatiere")
public class ProfMat implements java.io.Serializable {

 private ProfMatId id;
 private Professeur professeur;
 private Matiere matiere;

 public ProfMat() {
 }

Comment: Then add mapping to your `hibernate.cfg.xml` if you used it.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.maroclance.university.model;

// Generated 19 sept. 2014 13:34:26 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
* Matiere generated by hbm2java
*/
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "matiere", catalog = "gestionmatiere")
public class Matiere implements java.io.Serializable {

private int id;
private String nomMatiere;
private int coefficient;
private Set<ProfMat> profMats = new HashSet<ProfMat>(0);
private Set<Module> modules = new HashSet<Module>(0);

public Matiere() {
}

public Matiere(int id, String nomMatiere, int coefficient) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nomMatiere = nomMatiere;
    this.coefficient = coefficient;
}

public Matiere(int id, String nomMatiere, int coefficient,
        Set<ProfMat> profMats, Set<Module> modules) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nomMatiere = nomMatiere;
    this.coefficient = coefficient;
    this.profMats = profMats;
    this.modules = modules;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "nom_matiere", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getNomMatiere() {
    return this.nomMatiere;
}

public void setNomMatiere(String nomMatiere) {
    this.nomMatiere = nomMatiere;
}

@Column(name = "coefficient", nullable = false)
public int getCoefficient() {
    return this.coefficient;
}

public void setCoefficient(int coefficient) {
    this.coefficient = coefficient;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "matiere")
public Set<ProfMat> getProfMats() {
    return this.profMats;
}

public void setProfMats(Set<ProfMat> profMats) {
    this.profMats = profMats;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "matiere")
public Set<Module> getModules() {
    return this.modules;
}

public void setModules(Set<Module> modules) {
    this.modules = modules;
}
```

}

Comment: Don't post a comment like an answer.

Comment: im very blocked i dont know how to post a code in a comment